# Copying objects from a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have class object and it's constructor is defined.

```
class ClassOne {
private:
    classTwo object;
    string name
public: 
    classOne(ClassTwo* o, string* n){
        object = *o;
        name = *n;
    }
```

Does the constructor make a copy of the dereferenced pointers? Are `object` and `name` their own independent variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the constructor make a copy of the dereferenced pointers? Are `object` and `name` their own independent variables?

Yes and yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both. It copies the variables pointed to by the pointers. To not copy them, Object and Name would need to be pointers as well, and you would be passing the address to them via o and n.

As a side note, I am pretty sure objects will call a default copy constructor if none has been provided.

Comment: yeah, there is a copy constructor implemented for the classTwo. Thanks!

Comment: There's other options to avoid copying too, the members could be reference types, or a move c'tor could be invoked.